# Add the repo root as a Docker volume in a Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a CI pipeline for a repo in Jenkins using declarative pipeline.

The repo now contains its own Dockerfile at `.docker/php/Dockerfile`, which I want to use to build a container and run the pipeline in.

Normally, I get the code in the container using a volume in docker-compose.yaml:

```
    volumes:
        - .:/home/wwwroot/comms-and-push
```

...So I set up my Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {

    agent {
        dockerfile {
            dir ".docker/php"
            args "-v .:/home/wwwroot/comms-and-push"
        }
    }

    stages {

    ...
```

However, this results in an error when running the pipeline:

> `Error: docker: Error response from daemon: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters.`

I cannot specify the full path because I don't know it in this context -- it's running in some Jenkins workspace.

---

## What I've tried so far:

#### Using the WORKSPACE variable

```
        args "-v ${WORKSPACE}:/home/wwwroot/comms-and-push"
```

results in error:

> `No such property: WORKSPACE for class: groovy.lang.Binding`

#### Setting an environment variable before the pipeline:

```
environment {
    def WORKSPACE = pwd()
}

pipeline {

    agent {
        dockerfile {
            dir '.docker/php'
            args "-v ${env.WORKSPACE}/:/home/wwwroot/comms-and-push"
        }
    }
    ...
```

results in `${env.WORKSPACE}` resolving to `null`.

Comment: If you do nothing, Jenkins will mount `$WORKSPACE` to an identical file path; this should work for most routine build-and-test tasks.  Or when you ask Jenkins to build the image, you can specify the directory that is the build context when you `COPY` the application code into the image (you do not need to separately inject it at run time).  Does either of these approaches work for you?  If not, what `steps` are you running that need something different?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you -- Jenkins' default behavior is enough for my pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard Jenkins Docker integration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) already knows how to mount the workspace directory into a container.  It has the same filesystem path inside different containers and directly on a worker outside a container.  You don't need to supply a `docker run -v` argument yourself.

```groovy
agent {
    dockerfile {
        dir ".docker/php"
        // No args
    }
}

stages {
    stage('Diagnostics') {
        sh "pwd"  // Prints the WORKSPACE
        sh "ls"   // Shows the build tree contents
        sh "ls /" // Shows the image's root directory
    }
}
```

If you look at the extended Jenkins logs, you'll see that it provides the `-v` option itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the `docker.image.inside()` method, so in your case it is going to be something like `docker.image.inside("-v /home/wwwroot/comms-and-push:/home/wwwroot/comms-and-push:rw")`.